# unable to remove padding

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm having a an issue with my Wordpress site, Visual Composer and the RAW HTML module. I'm new to javascript and using the RAW HTML module.

I'm using the RAW HTML module to call up a youtube video in a specific way. However,

**extra padding is added to the top of the row that I can't seem to remove.**

I've tried adding negative margins to the bottom of the "Boost Your Chair" row and to the top of 2 columns below it, but nothing seems to work. That extra space is always there. Everything lays out fine if I remove the RAW HTML module and use a regular text or video module.

http://0cb.1d0.myftpupload.com

[extra padding between rows example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7VuJ.png)

Comment: welcome to SO, you'll get a better reception if you post the relevant code here...

Comment: Here are 2 places for you to consider: `<div class="vc_column-inner">` has a `padding-top: 35px`, AND `<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element">` has a `margin-bottom: 35px`.

Comment: Hope that helps. But now I need to vote to close your question because it doesn't adhere to the guidelines.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not sure what the code is that's causing the issue. I'll post the javascript code that's in the RAW HTML module, but there's no css in it. I believe it has to be inspected on the page .

Comment: I'm on Chrome on a PC. Just hit F12 and launch dev tools. All source files are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the offending selector:

```
.vc_row-has-fill+.vc_row-full-width+.vc_row>.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner
```

Try putting this in your css:

```
.vc_row-has-fill+.vc_row-full-width+.vc_row>.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner {padding-top: 0 !important;}
```